# inner join me repite los datos

Tags: mysql

Hola buenos días a todos, chicos consulta, estoy enredado con una query, necesito mostrar datos de 3 tablas diferentes, lo consigo, pero me repite los datos (filas), le he dado varias vueltas y no doy con el drama jeje, alguien ve algo raro:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`administrador`@`%` PROCEDURE `spMostrarHorasAtencion`()
BEGIN
SELECT
h.idHoraAtencion,
p.nombres, p.ape_pat, p.ape_mat,
h.dia,
b.numBox,
ho.hora
FROM
profesional p INNER JOIN horas_atencion h
ON p.idRegistro= h.idRegistro,
boxes_atencion b INNER JOIN horas_atencion h1
ON b.idBox = h1.idBox,
hora ho INNER JOIN horas_atencion h2
ON ho.idHora = h2.idHora;
END
```

Saludos a todos, gracias desde ya

Comment: puede mostrar una imagen , para diferenciar los indices de cada tabla?

Comment: Esas `,` en el from estan creando productos cartesianos que no filtras ni matcheas con ninguna clave, deberias mostrarnos las estructuras de las tablas para ver que sentido tiene esa query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo estas instanciando 3 veces a la misma tabla en el INNER JOIN, lo cual no tiene sentido.

Trate de normalizar tu sintaxis, prueba con este codigo:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`administrador`@`%` PROCEDURE `spMostrarHorasAtencion`()
 BEGIN
 SELECT
 h.idHoraAtencion,
 p.nombres, 
 p.ape_pat, 
 p.ape_mat,
 h.dia,
 b.numBox,
 ho.hora
 FROM horas_atencion h
 INNER JOIN profesional p ON p.idRegistro= h.idRegistro
 INNER JOIN boxes_atencion b ON b.idBox = h.idBox
 INNER JOIN hora ho ON ho.idHora = h.idHora;
 END
```

Trata de ponerle un identificador en duro, en caso que te traiga mas de 1 dato, habría que entrar a modificar el query según el requerimiento.

Comment: funciono impecable, gracias estimado, analizándolo claro, estaba repitiendo lo mismo varias veces...

Comment: ok @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid , que bueno que te sirvio. saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que agrupar los datos por valor, no se como tengas la tabla, pero supongo que todas tienen un valor por el cual puedas agruparlas, como por ejemplo una tabla de alumnos, los puedes agrupar por grado, por grupo o por carrera dependiendo de como la manejes

Comment: Hola Macx, tiene un campo en comun todas, como seria agruparlas como me meniconas, no entendi

Comment: seria ponerle la instruccion "group by" para que te agrupe los datos, y solo te los muestre una vez cada uno, si logro apreciar bien en tu consulta, creo que los podrias agrupar por p.nombres o por b.numBox

Comment: repetir los mismos datos pero con un group by?

Comment: lo que hace esa instruccion es que te agrupa todos los datos en un grupo indicado por la instruccion group by, y ya el resultado es que te muestra los registros sin que se repitan

Comment: si entendi el concepto, pero si lo llevo a la practica me arroja error 1055 :(... le añado GROUP BY h.idHoraAtencion; al final de la consulta

Comment: quitale el h solo pon idHoraAtencion